# How do I group an edit and some radio buttons?

Tags: delphi

I have to add one TEdit wit two radio buttons in a group of radiobuttons.
I was searching information but nothing helps me.

How I can add?

Comment: One way would be to put a TGroupBox on your form, and then you can put the TEdits and a number of individual TRadioButtons (rather than a TRadioGroup) in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Add a group box, `TGroupBox`, which will act as the container.
2. Add two radio buttons, `TRadioButton`, as children of the group box.
3. Add an edit, `TEdit`, as a child of the group box.

The radio group control, `TRadioGroup` is essentially a convenience control. You could implement a radio group from a group box and a bunch of radio buttons, but since that is such a common task, the radio group control is provided to wrap up all those details for you.

In your scenario, you want something a little more flexible than is provided by a radio group, and so you have to populate the group box manually.

Comment: Okey, now I have to do that pressing the second radiobutton the Tedit be enabled.

Comment: You're welcome! Use the `OnClick` event handlers of the radio buttons, and in those handlers set the `Enabled` property of the edit control.

Comment: But i have to use a Radiogroup. Because i have to collect the position of ItemIndex. I have to do a RadiogroupButton and one tedit.

Comment: I need 4 radiobuttons and the last one i need that when this radiobutton is checked, the tedit has to be enabled=true

Comment: I use what you say and it works, but i have a problem. I dont know how to put the event Onclick. I dont know what i have to put.

Comment: Okey i have do it Thanks a lot!

Comment: need now that I lock radiobutton to stop being depressed